# How do I wrap HTML untagged text with <p> tag using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have to parse an HTML document into different new files. The problem is that there are text nodes which have not been wrapped with `"<p>"` tags, instead they having `"<br>"` tags at the end of each paragraph.

I want to wrap this text with `<p>` tags using Nokogiri:

```
<div id="f15"><b>Footnote 15</b>: Catullus iii, 12.</div>
<div class="pgmonospaced pgheader"><br/>
<br/>
End of the Project abc<br/>
<br/>
*** END OF THIS PROJECT XYZ ***<br/>
<br/>
***** This file should be named new file.html... *****<br/>
<br/></div>
```

Comment: I believe the DOM could be helpful for you. Every tag is some node, but the text is `textNode`. So it is the question of parsing siblings.

Comment: @Yuri: thank for your comment,
Yes i agree with you, can you provide me with some Nokogiri code to search it out..

Comment: Sorry, that is why it is only a comment, not the answer. I'm not the Nokogiri expert at all. But the case not even in Nokogiri. Read about XPath.

Comment: "they are having "<br>" tag at the end of each para graph"? Do you mean a sentence or paragraph? Typically a `<br>` forces a line-end but not a paragraph. A `<p>` tag marks a paragraph.

Comment: @theTinMan: thanks buddy, yes its a line or we can say its a raw text without any <p> tag

Comment: @NadeemYasin, if you have a suitable answer to your question, please create an answer using your findings, and then select it as the solution. Also remove it from your question. That way it will be marked as answered by the system. Good job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around some forums and doing some debugging locally, i have found the following solution to my problem.

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('path/to/html_file')
html_doc
html_doc.search("//br/preceding-sibling::text()|//br/following-sibling::text()").each do |node|
    node.replace(Nokogiri.make("<p>#{node.to_html}</p>"))
end
```