# Using Nokogiri to wrap root text nodes in <p>'s while keeping <a>'s and <span>'s inside to <p>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

'Given a string that looks like:

```
"<a href='/'>I am a link.<a> And I am a paragraph, maybe <span>with a span</span>.<br/>And I'm another paragraph."
```

... how could I use Nokogiri to wrap the paragraphs in `<p>`'s in a sensible way by including the inline elements and also remove the `<br/>` so that the output would be something like:

```
"<p><a href='/'>I am a link.<a> And I am a paragraph, maybe <span>with a span</span>.</p><p>And I'm another paragraph.</p>"
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937846/how-do-i-wrap-html-untagged-text-with-p-tag-using-nokogiri

Comment: That solution leaves the `<a>` and `<span>` outside the `<p>` and returns in a full html document, not a marked up fragment

Answer (score 0):

The right way is probably to use xslt but if you're just dealing with short fragments you could get away with:

```
str.split('<br/>').map{|p| '<p>' + p + '</p>'}.join
```